# Upgrading Capybara to latest version makes Gitlab CI fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab, gitlab-ci, capybara-webkit

I'm upgrading my Capybara to the latest version (up from 2.18.0) This causes the `normalized_whitespace` deprecation running to show up a lot when running my tests. I read that pulling the master branch of the gem fixes the issue, effectively it does but now my CI on Gitlab fails with:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /builds/products/micheticket/vendor/ruby/2.5.0/bundler/gems/capybara-webkit-77fdac424cd6/bin/webkit_server
```

Does anyone have any Idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `Capybara` and `capybara-webkit` are two different things, `Capybara` is the testing framework, and `capybara-webkit` is a driver you can configure to be used with `Capybara`. Since `capybara-webkit` includes a C portion it needs to be compiled on the platform it's being installed on which means having all of its dependencies (specific versions of QtWebkit, etc) available on the platform. Having those available by default has become rare because QtWebKit stopped development quite some time ago. `capybara-webkit` development has also stopped and the project is likely to be archived very soon. You're going to have a much easier time if you swap to testing using the selenium driver (headless Chrome or Firefox) or one of the new direct to Chrome via CDP drivers like [Apparition](https://github.com/twalpole/apparition) which are in beta currently but aim to provide the extra features that capybara-webkit had over selenium.

Comment: I said up from 2.18.0, meaning I'm updating from that version.

Comment: There seems to be plans for a 2.0.0 version of `capybara-webkit` from what I saw on their Github. I did try switching to Selenium and the `webdrivers` gem but ran into other issues.

Comment: @8vius Look at the dates of that talk about 2.0.0 -- It stalled and isn't going to happen.  The ending of QtWebkit development basically end the capybara-webkit project (as it did with Poltergeist/PhantomJS) - I am a committer on the `capybara-webkit` project and was on the emails a few weeks ago talking about it being archived soon.

Comment: Yeah you're correct. The issue I'm having with selenium and the webdrivers gem is that the project allows some real connections and I'm not sure how to set them like we had with Capybara-webkit

Comment: @8vius Thats why I linked to the Apparition driver.  That supports blacklisting urls like capybara-webkit did.

Comment: Thanks for you help, Thomas, I decided against apparition since it's fairly new and their build is currently failing, but I'm getting headway with the `webdrivers` gem, I'm gonna delete the question since it's no longer relevant.

Comment: @8vius I wouldn't delete the question - it provides good info for people who are dealing with the death of capybara-webkit

Answer (score 0):

I use a gem to manage and install the drivers. Webkit is deprecated. I would use the chrome driver.

gem 'chromedriver-helper'

Comment: chromedriver-helper is also deprecated. You'll want to swap to `webdrivers` for managing your `chromedriver` installation soon.